# Convert HTML Website to OSX .app

Tags: macos, conversion

I've just made a website using nothing but HTML, css & js all offline nothing fancy, and I was wondering how I could convert it into a standalone Mac OS X application?

I know you can get PhoneGap to make websites into Native iOS apps. I would like this, but instead for OS X apps, if possible.

Comment: Why not just open it in the browser?  What's your end-goal?  A single executable?

Comment: Hi, Its for my university assessment, and dumb teachers so I'd like a single .app for osx teachers and .exe for win32 (already sorted) so there are not loads of files floating around as it will be passed around on USB stick so if its a single executable then no lose ends

Comment: Just use a zip or tarball.

Comment: then the teachers will have to extract it each time and will see numerous files, i just want 1 file.

Comment: @OwenMelbourne, if you are concerned about a 'sensory overload' from a long list of files, I would put `index.html` (or similar file) in the root directory and then have all other files in a child directory. Then they would only see one file and one folder at first glance.

Comment: what happens if they copy only index.html to another? all the assets are then lost. There are lots of reasons i want it in a self contained, just seems no definate how to, just alternatives

Comment: You could run it in [Prism](http://prism.mozillalabs.com/) or [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com/), a site-specific browser. The only thing you'll have to worry about is the placement of the HTML files.

Comment: @OwenMelbourne is there anything preventing you from just uploading it to a real web server? Almost all universities offer a small amount of free web hosting for their students. Perhaps you could contact your university's IT department and ask if there's any student hosting where you can upload your files. Then you just have to give teachers a link. If I were a professor I would be very wary of opening a strange all-in-one website exe or the like.

Comment: @nhinkle Then again the professor seems willing to be running all the submitted exe's.

Comment: Owen, I don't know if there's a Mac equivalent, but it sounds like what you need is a ["WinRAR SFX module"](http://www.jackmccarthy.com/malware/WinRAR_Archive_Creation.htm) or some such. Perhaps you could wrestle any FOSS installer engine (those already have zipping data and code into the same package down pat) into doing your bidding.

Comment: @badp [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) has SFX support and is free and open source.

Comment: @slhck Have you tested this? I cannot get Fluid to open local `file://` URLs.

Comment: @DanielBeck I originally wanted to but didn't get too far. I wonder if it can be hacked to allow this, or maybe Prism can? I only tried Fluid back then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any other person looking for an answer, I just used Xcode, included the webkit framework and used webview for it.